# Notify user on exception

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am currently making a client to gather data from a webservice.
Sometimes the connection fails and I put a try catch to prevent the page from going to error page.
What I would like to do is to show a pop-up on exeption, to tell the user to try again.
I know about "alert" on JS, but can't really make it pop without user action (i.e. clicking a button).

Is this the wisest approach?
How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: You can add label to your page and if exception is raised, then add some message to the label.

Comment: You can absolutely make an alert pop w/o the user clicking on something.

Comment: How do you collect data from the webservice?

Comment: If you just add the `alert()` to the page from server-side code, outside of a JavaScript function, then it will run when the page loads.

Answer (score 3):

If you **really** need a popup, you don't have to have a user click a button to get it:

```
var alertWindow= window.open("", "", "width=200,height=200");
   alertWindow.document.write("I know about: YOUR THING HERE");
```

However, popups are annoying and I would really suggest that you have a `<div>` in your main page with an `id="exceptionDiv"` and then doing something like this:

**page.html**

```
<div id="exceptionDiv"></div>
```

**page.js**

```
var exceptionDiv = document.getElementById("exceptionDiv");
exceptionDiv.innerHTML = "I know about: YOUR THING HERE";
```

Comment: This is exactly what I would do. No annoying popup. Just have a div display the error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I was about to try this approach (which seems to suit me), but I am using .cs code behind, so how can I "getElementById" of an element when I am not using script?

Sorry If I'm not very clear, but I'm not that enlightened on this subject.

Thank you once again.

Comment: Just a heads up.
I tried the ViewBag approach and it worked fine.

Thank you all.